# SQL - Convert data type varchar DD/MM/YYYY to date format in sql

Tags: sql, excel, vba, azure, date

I'm working on a Azure SQL database.

I'm trying to convert a field data type containing dates in dd/mm/yyyy format from a varchar(100) to a date field.  I am having no luck!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm no sql expert but using Microsoft SQL server management.

My column name is Eventdate and table name is customers.

I've tried but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

```
Select Eventdate
Where Customers
SELECT convert(varchar(100),Eventdate,101)
```

**EDIT:**

Whilst the answer to change varchar column to datetime worked a treat, I've now come up against another issue. I'll go into more detail on what the database is doing.

I have an excel spreadsheet that has the following vba code to connect to an sql database and insert the data to the SQL.

This is done by first sending it to an SQL table called 'MergeCustomers' checking for duplicate KeyID fields (JobCode) then putting it into the 'Customer' table.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String


    With Sheets("sql")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=tcp:SERVERADDRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=Sales;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"


        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            sJobcode = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sEventstatus = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            sVenue = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
            sGuestno = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
            sEventtype = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
            sClient = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)
            sEventdate = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)
            sCommission = .Cells(iRowNo, 8)
            sEventvalue = .Cells(iRowNo, 9)
            sEventmargin = .Cells(iRowNo, 10)
            sAccountman = .Cells(iRowNo, 11)

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.CustomersStage (Jobcode, Eventstatus, Venue, Guestno, Eventtype, Client, Eventdate, Commission, Eventvalue, Eventmargin, Accountman) values ('" & sJobcode & "', '" & sEventstatus & "', '" & sVenue & "', '" & sGuestno & "', '" & sEventtype & "', '" & sClient & "', '" & sEventdate & "', '" & sCommission & "', '" & sEventvalue & "', '" & sEventmargin & "', '" & sAccountman & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop

        conn.Execute "EXEC dbo.MergeCustomers"

        MsgBox "File saved and data successfully uploaded to the cloud"

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

After changing the 'Eventdate' columns in both the MergeCustomers and Customers sql tables I get the following error when running the VBA code in excel:

"the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

I think I need to change the output of the excel file to match the change in the sql data type?

I've copied the merge procedure I have running on the SQL below.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MergeCustomers] AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

MERGE dbo.Customers AS Trgt
USING dbo.CustomersStage Src
    ON Trgt.Jobcode  = Src.Jobcode
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Jobcode, Eventstatus, Venue, Guestno, Eventtype, Client, Eventdate, Commission, Eventvalue, Eventmargin, Accountman)
    VALUES (Src.Jobcode, Src.Eventstatus, Src.Venue, Src.Guestno, Src.Eventtype, Src.Client, Src.Eventdate, Src.Commission, Src.Eventvalue, Src.Eventvalue, Src.Accountman)
WHEN MATCHED AND
    (
        ISNULL(Trgt.Eventstatus, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Eventstatus, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Venue, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Venue, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Guestno, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Guestno, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Eventtype, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Eventtype, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Client, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Client, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Eventdate, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Eventdate, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Commission, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Commission, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Eventvalue, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Eventvalue, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Eventmargin, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Eventmargin, '')
    OR
        ISNULL(Trgt.Accountman, '') <> ISNULL(Src.Accountman, '')
    )
THEN
    UPDATE SET Eventstatus = Src.Eventstatus, Venue = Src.Venue, Guestno = Src.Guestno, Eventtype = Src.Eventtype, Client = Src.Client, Eventdate = Src.Eventdate, Commission = Src.Commission, Eventvalue = Src.Eventvalue, Eventmargin = Src.Eventmargin, Accountman = Src.Accountman
    ;

DELETE FROM dbo.CustomersStage
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Eg, [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: @SamMitchell . . . Dates are stored in an *internal* format, which has nothing to do with a string.  So, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the OP wants to convert a text field to a date field `from a varchar(100) to a date field.`

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm.

Are you looking to view the date by converting it from `VARCHAR` to a `DATE` format only  via SQL statement? Or modify the data type of the **column** entirely?

**EDIT:**

Could you give more info about your table as well as maybe a row or two of the data that is already there.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

I'll take a stab at the dark without further details.

Try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
ALTER TABLE Customers
ALTER COLUMN Eventdate DATETIME
```

Comment: I'm looking to modify the data type column entirely.  The raw data the column is varchar(100)

Comment: @SamMitchell update the question and explain what you want to do, what you tried, what was the problem.

Comment: Sorry - also to add.  The data will be updated all the time and more varchar info will be added so I need it to modify the data to date format as it goes into the sql

Comment: @SamMitchell If I understood correctly, you may need to consider to change your solution to add `more data`of `eventdate` in to the table by `DATETIME` in the first place and not as `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Thank you that's sorted it! Very much appriciated

Comment: @RevXaisks Yes I think this is my problem.  I've expanded on what I'm trying to achieve in the question as changing to DATETIME in the tables has caused me an issue on the data import on this field.

Comment: @SamMitchell The issue with your problem is because you are trying to interpret and pass the connection `conn.Execute` call as a `String` format by hard coding the whole thing in `"` double quotes `"`. This will throw an error at you of course as your `EventDate` is not in the `String` format. Could you also include your error output?

Answer (score 0):

Use convert function in sql to solve your problem. Below is the code.

```
--Create a sample table with EventDate column of varchar type 
Create Table Customers 
(
EventDate varchar(100)
)

Insert into Customers Values (GETDATE())

-- Declare a variable of varchar type to read customer table 
Declare @EventDate varchar(100)
Select @EventDate = EventDate from Customers


--Declare a new variable of the required data type of date  
Declare @EventDateInDateDataType Date 


-- use convert function to convert varchar to date format 
Select @EventDateInDateDataType = CONVERT(Date,@EventDate,101) 
Select @EventDateInDateDataType
```